# Wordpress website producing errors

Tags: wordpress, plugins, content-management-system, woocommerce

I have developed a wordpress eCommerce website that is producing errors and preventing the website from functioning to it's full potential, The error code has been provided below:

```
Warning: Division by zero in /home1/sandgco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-table-rate-shipping/woocommerce-table-rate-shipping.php on line 373

Warning: Division by zero in /home1/sandgco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-table-rate-shipping/woocommerce-table-rate-shipping.php on line 415
```

I have a feeling that the error may be occuring because of the way in which the plugin has been set up.

Does anyone have an idea as to why I am getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The division by zero means that you enabled the volumetric shipping without defining the volumetric divisor. This is a required field for it to work, otherwise the volumetric weight will always be 0 and the physical weight will therefor always win out.

Comment: what woocommerce plugins do you have?

Comment: Woocommerce, woocommerce colors, woocommerce sagepay direct, woocommerce table shipping rate, woothumbs, YITH woocommerce advanced reviews, YITH woocommerce wishlist. if that helps?